# Formulario con angular mediante ajax POST xhr.status devuelve 0 , no me devuelve 200 y me arroja error de promesa

Tags: ajax, angular, mongodb

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con angular, al realizar una peticion ajax por post el xhr.status no me devuelve 200, me devuelve 0. el formulario que intento enviar por post son datos de texto comunes mas un imagen. Porque podria devolveme 0?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

upload.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Global } from './global';

@Injectable()
export class UploadService{
    public url: string;

    constructor(){
        this.url = Global.url;
    }

    makeFileRequest(url: string, params: Array<string>, files: Array<File>, name: string){

        
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

            var formData:any = new FormData();
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
                formData.append(name, files[i], files[i].name);
            }

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(xhr.readyState == 4){
                    if(xhr.status == 200){
                        resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                    }else{
                        reject(xhr.response);
                    }
                }
            }

            xhr.open('POST', url, true);
            introducir el código aquí`xhr.send(formData);
        });
      }

   }
```

create.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Project } from '../../models/project';
import { ProjectService } from '../../services/project.service';
import { UploadService } from '../../services/upload.service';
import { Global } from '../../services/global';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-create',
  templateUrl: './create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create.component.css'],
  providers: [ProjectService, UploadService]
})
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {

  public title: string;
  public project: Project;
  public status! : string;
  public filesToUpload!: Array<File>;

  constructor(

    private _projectService: ProjectService,
    private _uploadService: UploadService

  ) {

    this.title = "Crear proyecto";
    this.project = new Project('','','','',2021,'','');

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  onSubmit(form:any){

    console.log(this.project)

    // guardar los datos

    this._projectService.saveProject(this.project).subscribe(response =>{
          console.log(response)
          if(response.project){
            console.log("response")
            // subir la imagen
            if(this.filesToUpload){
              console.log("files")
              console.log(this.filesToUpload)
            this._uploadService.makeFileRequest(Global.url+'upload-image/'+response.project._id, [], this.filesToUpload,'image' )
            .then((result:any) => {
              console.log("promesa")
              this.status = 'false';
              console.log(result)
              form.reset();

            })
          }else{
                        console.log("suces")
                        this.status = 'success';
                        form.reset();
                    }

          }else{
            console.log("failed")
            this.status = 'failed';
          }
      },
      error =>{
        console.log("error")
        console.log(<any> error)
      }

    )

  }

  fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any){

    this.filesToUpload = <Array<File>>fileInput.target.files;
   


  }

}
```

create.component.html

```
<div class="container">

    <h2> {{ title }} </h2>

    <div class="message success" *ngIf="status == 'success'" >
        El proyecto se ha creado correctamente, puedes <a href="">verlo aqui</a>
    </div>

    <div class="message failed" *ngIf="status == 'failed'" >
        El proyecto no se ha podido crear
    </div>

    <form #projectForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(projectForm)" >

        <p>
            <label for="">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="project.name" required>
            <span class="form_error"  *ngIf="name.touched && !name.valid" >

                El nombre es obligatorio

            </span>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="">Descripcion</label>
            <textarea type="text" name="description" #description="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="project.description" required></textarea>
            <span class="form_error" *ngIf="description.touched && !description.valid" >

                La descripcion es obligatoria

            </span>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="">Categoria</label>
            <input type="text" name="category" #category="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="project.category" required>
            <span class="form_error" *ngIf="category.touched && !category.valid" >

                La categoria es obligatoria

            </span>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="">Año</label>
            <input type="text" name="year" #year="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="project.year" >
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="">Lenguaje</label>
            <input type="text" name="langs" #langs="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="project.langs" required>
            <span class="form_error" *ngIf="langs.touched && !langs.valid" >

                El lenjuage es obligatorio

            </span>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="">Imagen del Proyecto</label>
            <input type="file" name="image" placeholder="Subir imagen" #image="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="project.image" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)">
        </p>

        <input type="submit" value="enviar" [disabled]="!projectForm.form.valid">
    </form>

</div>
```

Al enviar el formulario se guarda los datos en la base de datos con mongodb
pero la imagen no se esta subiendo. El codigo falla al querer subir la imagen.
No se si es una incompatibilidad con la version o si estoy haciendo mal la llamada. Al realizarlo con POSTMAN sucede lo mismo.
Algo que he notado es que al subir los datos a la base de datos mongodb, pierde se rompe la conexion y de ahi se corta el programa y devuelve ese error.
Otra cosa que sucede es que la ejecucion del servidor se rompe

De verdad que no entiendo. Agradeceria algun tipo de guia. Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @MauricioContreras gracias por el comentario, ahí subí el código de los componentes y servicios.